# Java: edit and recompile .jar?

Tags: java, open-source, jar, compilation, jgrapht

I downloaded JGraphT, and I want to make some changes to the core files. I'm using Eclipse. It wants a .jar or .zip to attach source files to the .class file. I have the .java file, but I'm not sure what I should do. Do I edit it, then recompile the jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by going to the Sourceforge Developer tab for JGraphT, and follow the instructions on checking out the latest source code :

```
 svn co https://jgrapht.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jgrapht jgrapht
```

Then create a project in Eclipse from the sources, and read through the README on how to build and deploy.